# How to create new code highlight style in rouge

Tags: github, jekyll, pygments, codehighlighter

I want to post my code on my Jekyll site highlight the code. I had successfully install rouge.

Is there a easy way if I want to create style on my own?

How can I install other's styles? And do you have something pretty style to recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Rouge is compatible with Pygments, code styles are the same.

In order to find css for Pygments or Rouge just google it : https://www.google.com/search?q=pygments+css